# Erro ao gerar APK usando framework Quasar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue.js-2, quasar

Estou tentando gerar o APK de um aplicativo feito com o Framework Quasar, mas recebo o seguinte erro:

```
$ quasar build -m cordova -T android

Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk (DEPRECATED)
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
     platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
```

Informações do cordova:

```
$ cordova requirements

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed 
android: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
Gradle: installed /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle
```

Já tentei instalar o Android target, mas ainda sem sucesso.

alguém já passou por esse mesmo problema?

Comment: Parece que você tem que usar o **Android Studio SDK Manager** para aceitar a licença e instalar SDK Platform e Build-Tools

Comment: Opa, já esta instalado o SDK e o Build-Tools

Answer (score 1):

Se o problema é só a licença você pode tentar aceitar executando o **SDK Manager** do Android Studio. *(atualizar/instalar um novo SDK pode fazer o menu de aceitar licença aparecer)*

[image: Imagem SDK Manage no android studio]

Ou tentar via Command-line usando `sdkmanager --licenses`: 
*(pode ser que a opção `--licenses` esteja 'deprecated', no meu sdkmanager ainda funciona)*

- Entre no diretório do **android-sdk** *(no seu caso parece ser `/usr/lib/android-sdk`)*;

  ```
   $ cd /usr/lib/android-sdk
  ```
- Dentro do diretorio do **android-sdk** entre no diretorio `tools/bin`

  ```
   $ cd tools/bin
  ```
- Aceite as licenças, execute o `sdkmanager` passando como parametro `--licenses` para ele mostra as licenças.

  ```
   $ ./sdkmanager --licenses
  ```

---

#### Uma outra possibilidade

Você pode estar com 2 ou + locais como o **android-sdk**. 
Exemplo: Seu **Android Studio** esta usando o android-sdk que fica em seu diretorio `/home/nomeDoUsuario` e **Quasar**/**cordova** usando o android-sdk que fica no diretorio `/usr/lib/android-sdk`.

Se esse for o caso você vai ter que ajustar isso para usar 1 só, ou aceitar a licença/instalar o SDK Platform e Build-Tools nos 2/+ android-sdk

[Android Studio - Command line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line)

Comment: boa, rodei o ./sdkmanager --licenses , aceitei as licenças, mas quando fui gerar novamente o APK deu o mesmo erro novamente.
vou verificar se está com o  2 ou + locais o android-sdk.